# Computer doesn't start when 12V CPU power plugged in

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, power-supply, atx

**Configuration (troubleshooting):**

**Board**: Socket AM3+ Gigabyte GA-78LMT-S2PT

**CPU**: AMD FX4300

**PSU**: 500W Peak

**Other components:**

**GPU**: ASUS Nvidia GTX960

**Mem**: 12GB (8+4) 1333

**HDD**: Seagate 1TB SATA

This machine was working before I moved it to another place.

**With only the PSU and board connected (CPU power connector unplugged)**, power seems to flow. If I add the GPU, it receives power too and the fans on it work. See: [http://i.imgur.com/6IeyKI7.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/6IeyKI7.jpg) (my phone is ancient, but I think the images are clear enough to convey what's happening)

**When I plug in the 12V CPU power, the machine doesn't start**. The fans momentarily start up for half a second then die. If I add a RAM stick, it's the same deal. And so for any other additional devices. Basically, it's probably due to the CPU power being plugged in.

I've checked the pins on the CPU power connector and I get a 12V reading. (See: [http://i.imgur.com/z6lXOcT.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/z6lXOcT.jpg)) So I don't think the connector is busted. Without the connector plugged in, the devices on the board (except the CPU) seem to receive power.

The whole story:

The machine was working before being moved. After it was moved, it started up a couple times and turned off within a few minutes. Later, it seemed to start up with everything but the GPU connected, but I didn't have a VGA cable to check the output. I didn't hear a POST beep though. I think 500W was sufficient for it to work with the GPU plugged in though because it was working well enough before being moved. Then finally the machine died completely and wouldn't start at all.

I think the CPU is most likely the part that is dead. If not that, then the board. The PSU seems fine because it can operate the fans without going through the board and shows the expected readings on the pins.

I'm not really all that experienced when it comes to hardware troubleshooting. I can tinker here and there and put a machine together, but I can't say with certainty what's wrong here. I'm also a bit tight on cash right now, so I need to know which part needs replacement so I may only change that particular one and not buy a whole new machine.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Humor me and try with a known good decent psu

Comment: dont do that :-) at least dont power up without the GPU power wires connected when gpu is sloted, it will make things worse. The fans running is nothing, no post beep anyways. Replace the PSU , then the motherboard.  I read about 2 people jamming the 12v power plug in , after the PSU turned on :-) , really bad form.  In thier case something had gone wrong with the motherboard power stuff itself. Ahh nothing to lose.  Best if you get the on-board or on-die grafics going first too without the GPU in the picture , until the rest of it is working fully.